# Commas before non-restrictive subordinating conjunctions?

Tags: commas, subordinate-clauses, dependent-clause, non-restrictive

It's said that a comma shouldn't be placed before a dependent clause when it comes after the independent clause, but what about when the dependent clause is non-restrictive? For example:

> "*I can't go shopping today, since I have no money.*"

In that sentence, "*since I have no money*" is the dependent clause but it's also a non-restrictive cause, right? If so, would it be wrong to have a comma before it? I've always heard not to place a comma before the dependent clause, but what about when it's non-restrictive? Would it be adviceble to have one? Somewhat like this sentence:

> "*I'm a fan of his writings, though I don't really keep up with that he's doing.*"

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with *since I have no money* being non-restrictive. It is an essential piece of information. However the alternative construction does take a comma

*Since I have no money, I can't go shipping.*

Interestingly, especially in dialogue, you can use a comma with your clause  if the intention is to make it an aside

*He said, "I can't go shopping, since I have no money."*
 In this case an em-dash or ellipses would also work.

**Your clause is restrictive; thus it does not take a comma when following an independent clause.** However it would take a comma if it precedes the independent clause or if its intention is as a parenthetical element.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the significance of mentioning the bit about dialogue? In that case, we are dealing with a different scenario, right?

Comment: It gives the reader the sense of a pause or perhaps even something muttered.

Comment: I understand. I just hate it and I think people do not generally have a reason to pause right there so hard. Honestly, when I see the comma separating the tag, I count it just as that, a tag, nothing more. If I counted it as more, it would feel like we are separating the direct object from the verb, which I don't like. Quirk et Al talked a lot about this in the CGEL, but he seemed to think of these constructions as a "gradient of their own".

Answer (score 0):

Ethan, the comma is better but not mandatory in that example. (Better to use 'because' rather than 'since' though.) Your second example is a better illustration of why the comma is better.